# I need help updating my Node version on my Mac in order to use Next JS, I keep getting an error even though its installed

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, next.js

I'm creating a new NextJS App and its saying it requires a newer version of Node >= v18.17.0 in order to work with Next JS. I've been trying to update, but its saying the active node version is different from the installed node which is the one i want to use.

I followed these instructions : https://medium.com/macoclock/update-your-node-js-on-your-mac-in-2020-948948c1ffb2. I also manually installed from https://nodejs.org/en/download/current. These are the errors I'm getting :
[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm confused as to why the paths are different. Did I mess something up?
Also is any change to this going to effect my other projects? I have a Next JS app that I made last year and that hasn't had any issues.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your Next.js form 12 to 13
run this cmd -

> npm i next@13 react@latest react-dom@latest eslint-config-next@13

for more refer this- https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/upgrading/version-13